# PHP imagecopyresampled() produces image border on one side

Tags: php

I have a resampling script that centers resampled images on a square canvas. 
For horizontally-oriented images that are centered vertically on a white background a line is added along the BOTTOM edge of the resampled image. 
For vertically-oriented images that are centered horizontally the line appears on the RIGHT edge of the resampled image.

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($th_width, $th_height);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, $th_x, $th_y, 0, 0, $th_width, $th_height, $src_width, $src_height);

$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $bgcolor);
```

The line is there regardless of background fill, it just shows up most on white.
[image: Resample border issue]

What causes this? No amount of adjusting parameter values will get rid of it (they just offset the resampled image on the background or distort it).

Answer (score 0):

I am providing my own workaround for this issue.
It appears the image border artifact is a COMBINATION result of 'imagecopyresampled()' AND centering offsets.  If I just resample the image as-is THEN center and fill the image, the border is avoided. Here is the workaround:

1) RESAMPLE your image as-is (same aspect ratio) then SAVE to retain changes:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($res_width, $res_height);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $res_width, $res_height, $src_width, $src_height);

// SAVE new image - set quality to lossless since reusing it:
imagejpeg($thumb, "resampled/output_temp.jpg", 100);
```

2) Retrieve the temporary image:

```
$file = "resampled/output_temp.jpg";
$image = file_get_contents($file);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($image);

// Get the RESAMPLED image dimensions
list($src_width, $src_height) = getimagesize($file);
```

3) NOW apply CENTERING and FILL:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($th_width, $th_height);

// COPY the image
imagecopy($thumb, $source, $th_x, $th_y, 0, 0, $src_width, $src_height);

$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);

// Replace default black background - this must be placed AFTER imagecopy()
imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $bgcolor);

// Save image (uses default quality setting 75)
imagejpeg($thumb, "resampled/" . $newfile);

// Optionally free up memory:
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

The result is a clean image. 
For correcting incomplete imagefill() on the background when centering vertically-oriented images see this post:
[imagecopyresampled() results in split color background imagefill()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333946/imagecopyresampled-results-in-split-color-background-imagefill)